# What is the difference between observer(design pattern), eventbus(greenroboto), LiveData(Android)?

Tags: observer-pattern, greenrobot-eventbus, android-livedata

I'm unable to distinguish what to use.
It seems are all working in a same way but different way but the base logic are same, kindly let me know what is the main difference in all?

Comment: The observer pattern allows us accomplish something extraordinary in software architecture. What that allows us to accomplish is low coupling, high cohesion. What that means is, we are able to avoid connecting all of our class instances together via references in code, but maintain a system of these objects that communicate via an event bus system. In other words,instead of passing references of objects back and forth to allow us to make a callback on a parent activity,for example, we can use EventBus instead.You’ll begin to understand this better when we go through the code in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EventBus` is just some kind of tool that has been written with **Observer-like** situations in mind. The general usage of `EventBus` is to **fire events** so we can use of the word Observer to fit for it. Observer pattern **uses events or messages to notify of a change** to objects of interest about the object being observed(changed).

And `EventBus` is also **not observer** pattern because if you have N objects and you want to communicate between all of them you need N*N observers if you use the observer pattern but only one global `EventBus` is enough to do the same job.

So `EventBus` is the EventBus-pattern.

---

And `LiveData` is also considered as an **observable data holder class** that used in Observer pattern. Unlike a regular observable, `LiveData`is **lifecycle-aware**, meaning it respects the lifecycle of other app components, such as activities, fragments, or services.

So `LiveData` is the Observer pattern for Android, or can be considered the separate LiveData-pattern.

Comment: Second paragraph is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24915411/1371329).