# What do you call a pattern that uses a eventBus to interact with all its components ( Slides / Dots / Arrows )

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have been playing around for a while with the code of glide.js and have been quite facinated by the design pattern used in Glide.js , that looks something like below, below is just the edited gist of the code , but i really have never seen something quite like this :-

The full code can be found [HERE](https://github.com/glidejs/glide/blob/master/src/index.js#L9).

```
import defaults from './defaults'
import { warn } from './utils/log'
import { mount } from './core/index'
import { mergeOptions } from './utils/object'
import { toInt, isObject, isArray } from './utils/unit'

import EventsBus from './core/event/events-bus'

export default class Glide {
  /**
   * Construct glide.
   *
   * @param  {String} selector
   * @param  {Object} options
   */
  constructor (selector, options = {}) {
    this._c = {}
    this._t = []
    this._e = new EventsBus()

    this.disabled = false
    this.selector = selector
    this.settings = mergeOptions(defaults, options)
    this.index = this.settings.startAt
  }

  /**
   * Initializes glide.
   *
   * @param {Object} extensions Collection of extensions to initialize.
   * @return {Glide}
   */
  mount (extensions = {}) {
    this._e.emit('mount.before')

    if (isObject(extensions)) {
      this._c = mount(this, extensions, this._e)
    } else {
      warn('You need to provide a object on `mount()`')
    }

    this._e.emit('mount.after')

    return this
  }
}
```

Notice how an instance of a eventBus is passed to each component (which can be a Arrow Component, Slider Component, Dots Component) of the slider plugin. This instance of eventBus than is used to communicate between all the components. I have a faint idea of how the pub/sub pattern works in JS. but What exactly is this pattern and what are the advantages of using it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the implementation, it may be considered as an [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), or a [Mediator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern).

This subject was already treated here: [Is Eventbus a Mediator or Observer Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975061/is-eventbus-a-mediator-or-observer-pattern)

Answer (score 4):

EventBus pattern mostly used for subscribing/publishing events on top level by maintaining loose coupling principle on your application. The subscribers of publisher never knows the source of it.

**It is close to Observer pattern** because of publishers and subscribers. **But a class which uses EventBus for firing events cannot be named as Observer class**. It just contains an implementation of EventBus.

The advantages;

1. It just simplifies communication between classes.
2. Also can be useful for centralization of activities like logging, alerts etc.